# Show last commits of a given author in git?

Tags: git

I have been asked to produce stats on our Git repository. We have some developers that appear to be unproductive lately and I was told to list the last N commits of a given author (and yes, I hate being forced to do that...).

I tried `git log --author=Bob` which works well, but only on the current branch. I'd like to find all the last commits, in all existing branches.

How can I achieve that ?

Comment: In short, `--all` is what you need.

Comment: @slhck: Obvious and I missed it. Thanks ;) Voting to close as this is indeed a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

you can combine `git log --author=Bob` with `for each` loop in shell script.

1. `git branch -l` - will give you all the local branches
2. `git branch -r` - will give you all the remote branches